# Reading an integer from the command prompt in Java using Scanner

Tags: java, input, integer

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test
  {
    public static void main(String args[])
      {
        Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("\nEnter number:");

        int num_shapes = input_scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("\n%d", num_shapes);
      }
  }
```

Each time the program is run, I enter an integer, press the enter key, am taken to a new line, enter a new integer, and hit the enter key again.  The first integer is then displayed.

How can I get it to display the first integer directly after it is entered, without having to enter a second integer?

I've tried it with and without

```
    input_scanner.nextLine();
```

following the line containing 'nextInt()', but get the same thing either way.

Any help in resolving this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its working perefectly no need to enter second number

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with your code; are you sure that it's this exact code that's showing the issue?

Comment: Its working perfectly in my case too....

Comment: it is working fine in my ide

Comment: works fine... you need a break, call your GF!!!

Comment: Code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

this works perfectly

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainclass{

   public static void main(String args[])
     {
       Scanner input_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter number:");

       int num_shapes = input_scanner.nextInt();

       System.out.println(num_shapes);
     }
 }
```